# Hide a set number of list objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple list objects with the same structure on a page:
Example:

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
<div class="listWrapper">
<ul>
<li>Object One</li>
<li>Object Two</li>
<li>Object Three</li>
<li>Object four</li>
<li>Object five</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="listWrapper">
<ul>
<li>Object One</li>
<li>Object Two</li>
<li>Object Three</li>
<li>Object four</li>
<li>Object five</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, how can I set it so that for each list, only the first 3 objects are showing in each list and the rest are hidden?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:gt()` pseudo selector which select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```
$('.listWrapper').find('li:gt(2)').hide();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LPtjV/1/)**

Comment: Why use `.find()` and not just a single selector `.listWrapper ul li:gt(2)`

Comment: Because it will select all the li's as one set and then apply `:gt(2)` on it giving the wrong result, where as `find` will run on each `listWrapper` container and then apply `:gt(2)` on the matched li's.

Comment: We don't need `ul` also just `li:gt(2)` is enough, modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the `:gt()` (greater than) selector:**

```
$('.listWrapper ul').find('li:gt(2)').hide();
```

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73gXa/1/)

It's necessary to query the targeted `li`s in two passes using an additional `find()`. Otherwise if there are multiple `ul`s, all `li`s will be treated as a single collection, and only 3 total list items will be shown. **This way we `hide()` selected items as many times as there are lists.**

*NOTE:* You want your initial query to get down to the list itself.

See `:gt()` selector [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).

Comment: Ah, you'll have to go with @ShankarSangoli's answer then, which takes care of this by querying the items in two passes. (updated)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GEbxG/

```
$('div.listWrapper li').each(function(i, elem) {
  if($(elem).index() < 3) return;
  $(elem).hide();
});
```

Comment: That's why I upvoted @ShankarSangoli 's answer.  Yay simultaneous answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.listWrapper li').show().slice(3).hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

You can remove the `.show()` if all elements are visible initially.

---

If you don't already have the jQuery object containing all the `li` elements and/or don't need access to the full element list, you can avoid selecting them at the first place:

```
$('.listWrapper ul li:gt(2)').hide();
```